# How to change the URLs of a subsite in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Is it possible to rename the endpoints of a subsite in Yesod?

For instance, instead of using the provided [/login](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/master/yesod-auth/Yesod/Auth/Routes.hs) or [/email/register](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.8/yesod-auth-1.4.21/Yesod-Auth-Email.html) from [yesod-auth](https://www.stackage.org/lts-10.8/package/yesod-auth-1.4.21), I want to call them "/entrar" and "/cadastrar" (their PT-BR counterparts, respectively).

The only way I managed to do that was by setting my `stack.yaml` to use a modified local copy of `yesod-auth`, but I wonder if there's a better approach.

Comment: I wrote an article describing a better approach here: https://jezenthomas.com/rewriting-routes-in-yesod/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the `YesodAuth` datatype doesn't provide a way to change those routes, so you have two options as far as I know:

1. Have a local copy of `yesod-auth` and modify it according to your needs (What you're doing right know)
2. Have the routes you want in `config/routes` and a handler for each of them that will redirect to the `yesod-auth` routes:

**config/routes**

```
/entrar MyauthEntrarR GET
```

**src/Handler/Myauth**

```
getMyauthEntrar :: Handler Html

getMyauthEntrar = redirect LoginR
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Indeed, a simple redirect is a nice workaround... :)